# SLD style - pointN: position the label in the lower left corner

Tags: polygon, labeling, sld

I am trying to position the label in the lower left corner.

The idea is to get the vertex using the pointN function. But the label is not showing anywhere.

[image]

Validation and legend preview is OK.

Here is my code:

```
<Rule>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>50001</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <TextSymbolizer>

        <Geometry>
          <ogc:Function name="pointN">
            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Geometry>


        <Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>date</ogc:PropertyName>
        </Label>
```

Error from Log:

> WARN [lite.gridcoverage2d] - Could not reduce the grid geometry inside the valid area bounds: ReferencedEnvelope[-28.5 : 61.5, -85.0 : 85.0]
> Grid geometry isGridGeometry2D[GridEnvelope2D[0..1652, 0..367], PARAM_MT["Affine",
> PARAMETER["num_row", 3],
> PARAMETER["num_col", 3],
> PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.4970798039415638],
> PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 668572.647161748],
> PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -0.49707980394384876],
> PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 5066033.103524317]]]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: looking at too high a scale? try removing the `<Geometry>` and see if it shows up then, this will tell you where the problem might be, then look in the log file to see what that says

Comment: @IanTurton the scale is ok, I just edited my post with error from log

Comment: Are you using EPSG:3857 and looking above (or below) 85N(S)?

Comment: @IanTurton EPSG is 3765